# What is Baskwat in The Upside?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I would like to know what is Baskwat in the movie 'The Upside'.
I think he or she is an artist, but Dell says it wrong.

> Dell: Who knows, man? I may be the next--the next **Baskwat**.

Somebody please helps me. 
I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 3):

Jean-Michel Basquiat was an American artist of Puerto Rican and Haitian descent, active in New York from the late '70s to the late '80s. He died in 1988 of a heroin overdose. Works by Basquiat now sell for millions of dollars. In 2017 his "Untitled (1982)," a painting of a skull, sold at auction for over $110 million – the most ever paid for an artwork by an American. It is likely that Baskwat is a misspelling (or reflects a mispronunciation) of Basquiat.

Answer (score 0):

Basiquiat is misspelled “Baskwat” on purpose, because that’s how Dell’s character pronounces it...he’s not schooled in art history.